# Oracle apex create page that does not use page 0 master template

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a master template for my app , page 0 and every page that I create inherits this template. I however want to create a page that does not use this template within my application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new page template with whatever formatting you want for this page and assign it to the page instead of the default by selecting it from the drop-down list in Page Attributes.

[image]